# What is the Best method for multiple Data Storing and Fetching?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following table each `owner` has his own page, When someone visits it, All the `Seats` with `SecretCodes` appears

```
OwnersSeats
[id    -  ownderid -  type        -  Seat1  -  SecretCode2                            -> Seat50  - SecretCode50              ]
[1     -  3        -  Premium     -  Mark   -  v2ttvgwrxt5cg36g3c63g36c3c54c26y4e73c6 -> Max     - c4wghwh65qcg45g5qx3       ]
[2     -  3        -  Standard    -  Jerry  -  36vyh36cyh6y6wc363v636vc3yc6y3v7y37    -> Marco   - h7wv5cg6qg6qcgqx3xgf5qwy4h]
[3     -  7        -  Enterprise  -  Sonia  -  c3m73uhyv73vyhu3h33c65g33c7v373v73v7   -> John    - 5ctev5hmkbjev7h7kje       ]
```

With each `Seat* VARCHAR(24), SecretCode* TEXT` `Can be VARCHAR(512) instead.`

Then I select them using this Query

`SELECT ownderid, type, Seat1, SecreCode2 -> 50 FROM seats WHERE ownerid = :ownerid`

What is the best way to handle this to be Efficient, Well preformed and Easier to Use and Edit?

I thought about storing all the seats in array inside the table as a `TEXT` like this

```
$SS = [
s1 => 'Mark', sc1 => 'v2ttvgwrxt5cg36g3c63g36c3c54c26y4e73c6', 
s2 => '~~', sc2 => '~~~~~~~',
s3 => '~~', sc3 => '~~~~~~~',
s4 => '~~', sc4 => '~~~~~~~', -> 50
];
```

But i don't know if that Good or Bad for Performance.

I want to `limit` it to `50`, So i have `100 column[SS]` `50 Seats` `50 SecretCode`, Do I use `normalization` to handle this?

I thought it would be better to put all the `SS` in a Single row to be fetched all at once with all the `ownerid` data, Since i suppose it would be faster.

Also I don't know how can i fetch all the `SS` from a `normalized table` without using `second query` to fetch all the releated data from it or using`GROUP_CONCAT()`, So I wonder which one is better for performance to be used.

```
[OSid - Seat  - SecretCode                            ]
[1    - Mark  - v2ttvgwrxt5cg36g3c63g36c3c54c26y4e73c6]
~48                                                   ]
[1    - Max   - c4wghwh65qcg45g5qx3                   ]
[2    - Jerry - 36vyh36cyh6y6wc363v636vc3yc6y3v7y37   ]
~48                                                   ]
[2    - Marco - h7wv5cg6qg6qcgqx3xgf5qwy4h            ]
[3    - Sonia - c3m73uhyv73vyhu3h33c65g33c7v373v73v7  ]
~48                                                   ]
[3    - John  - 5ctev5hmkbjev7h7kje                   ]
```

Comment: `SELECT Seat1, SecreCode2 -> 50 FROM seats WHERE ownerid = :ownerid` is a real pain??? How? What?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have to write each one of them manually using `PHP` inside `SQL`, But after you asking me that, I realized that i should've used `array` with `foreach loop` to make my life easier. But is that Table Design Good?

Comment: It's hard to understand the bigger picture...

Comment: Are you having performance problems? When you're not sure what you're doing, the last thing you should do is store lots of separate data elements in one big TEXT. And don't say: "I'll deal with any problems that results in 'later'.".

Comment: @FirstOne for each `ownerid` he has `50 seat` with `50 secret code`, I either use `50 column x2 [100]` for a single `ownerid row`, Or make a single `column` And store all the `50seat with 50secretcode` in it to be used in `PHP Array.`

Comment: Or you could have a table with (at least) three columns: `ownerid`, `seat` and `secret code`.

Comment: The problem is, I think, that you want to restrict one value of `ownerid` to one row. Don't. If you have 100 entries for one `ownerid` it would make perfect sense to have 100 rows for that. Read up on 'database normalisation'.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see, third table is the way, But how could having all the 100 entry in a single row be worse than having it in 100 row separated?

Comment: That will become completely self-evident when you have learned what database normalisation is. Just as a start argument: Suppose one owner has only 50 entries, then you waste 50 columns, or what if another owner needs 150 entries, then you have to expand your table even futher. Moreso, databases have been optimized to handle many rows, more than dealing with many columns.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understood `normalization` a little, but i'm confused about something, How can i get all multiple the `Seats` with its `Secret Code` in the `Query`? Do i have to make a second Query for it? Because using `GROUP_CONCAT()` can't handle the unlimited rows. Also I'll need to limit the seats to `50` anyway, Do i still use normalization?

Comment: I'm sorry, from your question I cannot understand what your data table actually looks like, and so I cannot answer any questions about it or how to query a modified version of it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an answer, not a comment, because a comment is quite restricted. I think I start to understand your table. So I would rewrite the table with only these columns:

```
id
ownderId
type
seat  
secretCode
```

Data would look like this:

```
[id - ownderId - type       - seat   - secretCode                             ]
[1  - 3        - Premium    - Mark   - v2ttvgwrxt5cg36g3c63g36c3c54c26y4e73c6 ]
[2  - 3        - Standard   - Jerry  - 36vyh36cyh6y6wc363v636vc3yc6y3v7y37    ]
[3  - 7        - Enterprise - Sonia  - c3m73uhyv73vyhu3h33c65g33c7v373v73v7   ]
[4  - 3        - Premium    - Max    - c4wghwh65qcg45g5qx3                    ]
[5  - 3        - Standard   - Marco  - h7wv5cg6qg6qcgqx3xgf5qwy4h             ]
[6  - 7        - Enterprise - John   - 5ctev5hmkbjev7h7kje                    ]
```

If seat numbers are important to you, you could add a column with that number in it. Like this:

```
[id - ownderId - type       - seatNo - seat   - secretCode                             ]
[1  - 3        - Premium    - 1      - Mark   - v2ttvgwrxt5cg36g3c63g36c3c54c26y4e73c6 ]
[2  - 3        - Standard   - 1      - Jerry  - 36vyh36cyh6y6wc363v636vc3yc6y3v7y37    ]
[3  - 7        - Enterprise - 1      - Sonia  - c3m73uhyv73vyhu3h33c65g33c7v373v73v7   ]
[4  - 3        - Premium    - 50     - Max    - c4wghwh65qcg45g5qx3                    ]
[5  - 3        - Standard   - 50     - Marco  - h7wv5cg6qg6qcgqx3xgf5qwy4h             ]
[6  - 7        - Enterprise - 50     - John   - 5ctev5hmkbjev7h7kje                    ]
```

The table is now normalized. The same type of data is not present in multiple columns anymore. This would make your query look like this:

```
SELECT seatNo, seat, secreCode FROM seats WHERE ownerId = :ownerid
```

Any other query on the data would be similar.

Comment: Wouldn't creating a `2nd` table to hold `Seats` and `SecretCodes` be better in this case as you mentioned, to save some space of the duplicated `type` column? But i'm really confused, If I will always be limited to `100 SS` Why is it still better to have multiple columns? As i understood from you, MYSQL is faster processing `rows over columns`, But isn't having `50 row` take a lot of space?

Comment: Yes, you could have a separate table for `seat` and `secretCode`, with a pointer back to the table containing `ownerId` and `type`, that would be fine. I don't think performance will be an issue in your case, so no matter what you do, it will work. You would need tens of thousands of seats before you notice any difference in speed between the different implementation. However, if you ask: "What is the best way to handle this to be Well preformed and Easier to Use and Edit?", then the answer will always be: Normalize! Why exactly is explained in almost every piece ever written about it.

Comment: Ok, understood, One last newbie question, Is there any idea of having an `auto_increment id column` in the 2nd table? In the example I used `OSid - Seat  - SecretCode` only, But it is `id - OSid - Seat  - SecretCode` in the table, Sometimes i wonder if i should keep it or delete it.

Comment: Auto increment id's are often useful. They give you a column with an unique number for each row, so you can always refer to a particular row, if you want to. They also show you the order in which the rows where created. Remember, rows in a relational database have no order by themselves. Better keep it for now.